# Platform not setting [JAVA - Sandbox V201109]

Tags: google-ads-api

I AM FACING THIS PROBLEM WHEN MIGRATING API CODE FROM V201101, V13 TO
V201109.

In my Google campaign target, i tried adding Language and Platform and
mutated with Google API. In the return value I am seeing the two
targets being added i.e. Language and Platform.

1. In "Sandbox Account Viewer" I am seeing only "en" under Language
   and i do not see any Platform value.
2. Since #1 is not working, I tried using the writing an API call
   using the example GetAllCampaignTargets in the [link](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#9RD3n1d8sRQ/trunk/examples/v...google-api-adwords-php%7Cgoogle-api-adwords-python-lib%7Cgoogle-api-adwords-dotnet%7Cgoogle-api-adwords-ruby%7Cgoogle-api-ads-ruby%7Cgoogle-api-adwords-perl&sa=N&ct=rx&cd=2).
   Here I see total num entries is 6 but in the actual entries, only one
   entry is available with no targets.

Could anyone please help me to sort out the problem.

Thank you
Balaji

Answer (score 0):

The SandboxAccountViewer has not been upgraded to v201109 yet, so it won't show the exact same data.  The v201109 CampaignTargetService only returns AdScheduleTargets.  You'll need to use the CampaignCriterionService to get Languages and Platforms.

Best,
- Eric

P.S. The official AdWords API forum is here: http://code.google.com/apis/adwords/community/